# How do I recreate this color overlay layer effect in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, photoshop-effects

I would like to use the overlay effect used on the screenshot(s) below.

[image]

I've tried experimenting with several Blending modes but keep missing the mark. I'm sure this has a very easy answer but I'm having trouble recreating the effect on my own.

Here are a few more images for further context:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Black and white image layer, solid color layer over it, lower the opacity of the color layer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create a new layer and fill it with any color you want. Move this layer below the image you want to manipulate and set the layer Blend Mode of the image layer to `Multiply`. You can then modify the opacity of the image layer if you want, but it isn't necessary.

It may also help to desaturate or grayscale the image layer.

Comment: This got me the closest to what I was looking for. I used the Hue/Saturation Tool (move the 'saturation slider' all the way to the left) as a non-destructive means of converting the photo to b/w

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This answer did the job for me as well, right away, after a lot of my own failed experiments. Thanks.

Comment: @kelunik how do you grayscale just one layer?

Comment: @codecowboy: I've never used Photoshop, so I can't tell you. In GIMP it's just `Color` > `Grayscale`. There must be some similar filter in Photoshop.

Answer (score 5):

**Original image**

[image: Dream Theater Poster]

---

## Luminosity blend

Add a layer for your color and put it under your image.

Then use the blending mode "Luminosity" on that image. You can change the background color you want without changing the main picture.

[image: Use luminosity color blend to change color of an image]

## Color blend

Select your image layer, and go in the menu "Image", then select "Adjustment" and then "Desaturate."

Add a new layer with a color on top of that image and set it to the blending mode "Color."

[image: Blending color mode]

To add a more dramatic effect, you put the color image on top of these 2 layers and use the "Overlay" blending mode at 60% transparency. It will create an Instagram style filter effect.

[image: Instagram kind of effect]

## Another way (useful for Pantone and Spot printing)

Use the color mode "Duotone."

First set your image to grayscale mode, then Duotone mode in the menu "image/mode." Make sure to keep an original color version of your image!

Then in the Duotone menu, you can choose 1-2-3-4 colors and mix them together. The Duotone with 2 colors can be nice to add contrast. You can also play with the curves for each color to add more saturation or less wherever you want. You can use Pantones or CMYK or RGB color mixes.

If you need to keep this to print in spot colors or Pantone, you can save the image in EPS and leave it in Duotone mode. If you need it for web you can change the mode back to RGB. There's a slight color change that may happen but nothing dramatic.

[image: Image in Duotone for printing in spot or Pantones in Adobe Photoshop]

Answer (score 2):

i think best-way is use Hue/Saturation.

You can play with Hue/Saturation (*ctrl/cmd + B* **or** *image menu -> adjustments->Hue/Saturation* )

important!!! don't miss check colorize [image: don't missing check colorize]

Answer (score 0):

I guess in 1, 2, 3, 5 and 6 Photo Filters (Adjustments --> Photo Filters) are used and for 4 Filter Sketch Chrome is used (Filters --> sketch --> Chrome)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try a DUOTONE.

Here's a quick example:
[image]

This will also give you better control over the black levels without affecting the color rather than just using blending tricks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of ways to achieve this. Here is my solution:

-Ctrl+U, Saturation: -100 and Lightness: +50

-Create a new solid color layer and set it to Multiply

-Done

Answer (score 0):

There are two basic ways to create this effect in Photoshop.

Method 1: Add a solid color layer (`Layer > New Fill Layer > Solid Color...`) in the color you want, and change its Blend Mode to "Color" or "Hue" -- experiment to see which works best for the particular image.

Method 2: Add a Black and White Adjustment Layer, check the "Tint" checkbox and adjust the color to your preference. The advantage of this method is that you can now adjust the relative brightness of the colors in the original image using the sliders in the Black & White properties dialog.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For this type of Effect you can also run a command
Image menu -- Image Adjustment -- Photo Filter to an image.
Select any color you want to run on an Image with this Photo Filter command very easy with great effects.