# Create a gradient overlay on a photo

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, overlay

I'm trying to create a similar effect to this photo. With a blue and red overlay, but i cant seem to get more or less the same effect. i've tried to make a photo black and white and then apply the gradient overlay and make it multiply, but it does not really match at all. Any ideas to how this has been created?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. Add a `Black and White` adjustment layer above the image.
2. Add `Gradient` adjustment layer above the image.
3. Change blending mode to multiply.
4. Adjust opacity of gradient layer to fine-tune result.

Answer (score 2):

Step 1:

[image]

Let's add a little noise to the image to help the two photos blend more seamlessly together. Go up to the Filter menu at the top of the screen.

choose Noise, and then choose Add Noise. This brings up the Add Noise dialog box. Set the Amount to somewhere between 2-6% depending on the pixel dimensions of your image. I'm working on a low resolution image for this tutorial, so I'm going to set mine to 2% just to add a hint of noise. Make sure Distribution is set to Gaussian, and also make sure the Monochromatic option at the very bottom is checked.

[image]

Choose the original layer Click on the New Fill Or Adjustment Layer icon at the bottom of the Layers palette.

Then select Solid Color from the top of the list that appears. Photoshop's Color Picker will appear. Choose the color that you want to use for your image. I'm going to select a dark maroon for my color.

[image]

Similarly choose dark blue color for the crowd below.

Click OK once you've chosen a color to exit out of the Color Picker. Don't worry about choosing the "right" color at the moment because you can always change it later.

[image]

Now choose the desaturated layer. click on the Add A Layer Mask icon at the bottom of the Layers palette:

Select your Gradient tool from the Tools palette, or press G to quickly access it.Then, up in the Options Bar at the top of the screen, click on the down-pointing arrow to the right of the gradient preview area, which will bring up the Gradient Picker. Click on the black to white gradient in the top row, third from the left to select it.

hold down your Shift key and drag out a black to white gradient to blend the two images together. (black hides, white reveals concept of layer masking)

[image]

Thanks
Digiscape Gallery

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to say what are the perfect values here, but the effect is quite simple. Use dark gradient from red to blue, use color blend mode. Then make it all darker with overlay, say black 40%.

[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

Use the same techniques as shown on this question:

[How do I recreate this color overlay layer effect in Photoshop?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/30566/how-do-i-recreate-this-color-overlay-layer-effect-in-photoshop/58505#58505)

But instead of limiting yourself to one full colored layer, add other colored layers that have gradients and different blending modes.

In fact, since you want to have a portion in what looks like grayscale and the top colored with a gradient, you can use the "luminosity" blending mode and add a top layer with the colored gradient to it. It's also a non destructive technique and is very quick to apply! You can always add another darker gradient at the bottom to make that part darker.

## Examples:

Results will depend on what you want exactly and the picture you chose.

**Color + luminosity blending** (lighter result)

[image: color blending]

**Overlay + luminosity blending**

[image: overlay blending mode]

**More layers, more precision!**

You can add that semi-opaque effect by adding a top layer with some transparency.

[image]