# How is this 'one colour' design trend referred to in the design community?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, website-design, layer-style

I had thought that the current trend towards 'one colour photos' was being called 'monochrome' but can't seem to find any examples.

The attached picture illustrates what I am referring to. The photo has been darkened and edited to match the colour palette of the website.

[image]

The technique is referred to in [this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/30566/how-do-i-recreate-this-color-overlay-layer-effect-in-photoshop)

Comment: I have edited the question. If that is still not appropriate please delete it and apologies for the duplicate.

Comment: I think the proper term is 'colour overlay', as seen in the dupe that Scott suggested.